# Building, iterating over and invoking a list of expressions with different types

Tags: c#, dictionary, expression-trees

Consider the following definitions:

```
public class AlternateDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string AlternateDescription { get; }

    public AlternateDescriptionAttribute(string s)
    {
        AlternateDescription = s;
    }
}

enum Metasyntactic
{
    [AlternateDescription("Corge")]
    Foo,

    [AlternateDescription("Quux")]
    [Description("Qux")]
    Bar,

    Baz,
}
```

I would like to get the attribute values of these enums in order of precedence, which is AlternateDescription > Description > enum.ToString(). In other words, use the AlternateDescription  is it's there, fall back to Description if not, and fall back to ToString if neither are present.

To do this I've created the following helper method:

```
public static bool TryGetAttributeValue<TAttribute, T>(Enum field, Expression<Func<TAttribute, T>> valueExpression, out T value)
    where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var attribute = TryGetAttribute<TAttribute>(field);
    if (attribute == null)
    {
        value = default(T);

        return false;
    }

    value = valueExpression.Compile()(attribute);

    return true;
}
```

which is being used like so:

```
static string GetNiceDescription(Enum field)
{
    if (TryGetAttributeValue<AlternateDescription, string>(field, a => a.AlternateDescription, out string alternateDesc))
    {
        return alternateDesc;
    }

    if (TryGetAttributeValue<DescriptionAttribute, string>(field, a => a.Description, out string description))
    {
        return description;
    }

    return field.ToString();
}
```

However this is a bit clunky, especially since I have more than 2 attributes I'm interested in, and potentially more in the future. What I'd like to do is be able to put the attributes and their associated expressions into a list and just iterate over that - so far I've come up with the following:

```
static string GetNiceDescriptionViaExpressions(Enum field)
{
    Expression<Func<AlternateDescriptionAttribute, string>> exp1 = a => a.AlternateDescription;
    Expression<Func<DescriptionAttribute, string>> exp2 = a => a.Description;
    var expressions = new LambdaExpression[] { exp1, exp2, };

    foreach (var exp in expressions)
    {
        var attributeType = exp.Parameters[0].Type;
        var attributeInstance = field.GetType().GetField(field.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (attributeInstance == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var result = exp.Compile().DynamicInvoke(attributeInstance);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return (string)result;
        }
    }

    return field.ToString();
}
```

But that's inelegant and not particularly compile-time safe, I would much prefer if it was possible to write something like the following:

```
static string GetNiceDescriptionViaExpressions(Enum field)
{
    // attributeExpressionsDictionary would be a dictionary mapping
    // attribute types to expressions - not sure how that would look...
    foreach (var attribute in attributeExpressionsDictionary)
    {
        if (TryGetAttributeValue<attribute.Key, string>(field, attribute.Value, out description))
        {
            return description;
        }
    }

    return field.ToString();
}
```

Is this possible? If not, what improvements can be made to `GetNiceDescriptionViaExpressions` to make it more safe and/or performant?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using single attribute definition with `Weight` property and multiple annotations for  the `enum` field ?

Far easier is to have single attribute responsible for your descriptions.

**Attribute definition**:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DescriptionAttribute(int weight, string value)
    {
        this.Weight = weight;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public int Weight { get; }
    public String Value { get; }
}
```

The Weight property will be used as tie breaker which description to use.

**Here is how can be used to annotate enum:**

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
   [Description(1, "Official description"), 
    Description(2, "Alternate Description")]
   Val1,

   [Description(1, "Description")]
   Val2,

   Val3
```

}

**Implementation of the GetDescription method:**

```
public static String GetDescription<TEnum>(TEnum @enum) where TEnum: struct
        {
            var description = typeof(TEnum)
                .GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                .Single(x => EqualityComparer<TEnum>.Default.Equals((TEnum)x.GetValue(null), @enum))
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), inherit: false)
                .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Weight)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(@enum.ToString())
                .First();

            return description;
        }
```

**NOTE**: I am using a generic version to avoid boxing the enum value. With the current version the method can be used with any struct, which is not acceptable. My advice is to use runtime check if the passed value is actual enum to avoid future issues.

**Here is simple usage:**

```
// Official description
var fDescription = GetDescription(SomeEnum.Val1);

// Description
var sDescription = GetDescription(SomeEnum.Val2);

// Val3
var tDescription = GetDescription(SomeEnum.Val3);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware this question comes across as an XY problem, but that's the point - I do know there are simpler/better/faster ways to achieve the same end result, but it's not the result in this case that I'm interested in, but the methodology to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are overcomplicating this. I do not see the usefulness of Expression trees here at all. And if I understand correctly, your main question is about generics, and not expression trees. You want to have a collection of objects that have a varying generic parameter, and still be able to access them in a type safe way. As far as I know, there is not way to do that. E.g. you will always have to go somewhere through object/a base class, like in:

```
public class TestDescription : Attribute
{
    public string Desc {get; set;}
}

public interface ITextExtractor
{
    string GetText(Attribute attribute);
    Attribute GetAttribute(Enum field);
}

public class TextExtractor<TAttribute> : ITextExtractor
    where TAttribute: Attribute
{
    public Func<TAttribute, string> TextGetter {get; private set;}
    public TextExtractor(Func<TAttribute, string> getter){ TextGetter = getter;}
    public Attribute GetAttribute(Enum field)
    {
        return ...;
    }
    public string GetText(Attribute attribute) { return TextGetter((TAttribute)attribute);}
}
```

and then

```
    var possibleAttributes = new List<ITextExtractor>{
        new TextExtractor<TestDescription>(a => a.Desc),
        new TextExtractor<DescriptionAttribute>(a => a.Description)};

    foreach (var possibleAttribute in possibleAttributes)
    {
        var attribute = possibleAttribute.GetAttribute(field);
        if (attribute != null) return possibleAttribute.GetText(attribute);

    }
```

you also fall back to the Attribute baseclass in the Attribute base class and then have to cast for correct type.